# Using this.state.example too many times, how can I put this into a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using this.state.example on one of my JS files in react. How can I go ahead and add it to variable so it won't be as messy?

```
return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <header className="example">
      <h1>{this.state.test.products[i].name}</h1>
    </header>
```

I'd like to replace this.state.test.products

Comment: it would be way easier for us to help you if you would provide some code showcasing your issue.

Comment: @ChaimFriedman Updated

Comment: Please update complete code along with error message for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify like this:

```
const { products } = this.state.test;
```

and then use it:

```
const { products } = this.state.test;
return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <header className="example">
      <h1>{products[i].name}</h1>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pull it out into its own constant using es6 syntax

```
const { example } = this.state
```

Now you can just use 'example' instead of 'this.state.example' everywhere

Comment: const { test: { products } } = this.state

Answer (score 0):

const { products } = this.state.test

We use destructing syntax because we don't need to declare and assign values in steps.

For example,if you had three properties in this.state.test

Option 1 :-

```
const { a , b , c}  =  this.state.test;
```

Option 2  :-

```
const a  =  this.state.test;
const b  =  this.state.test;
const c  =  this.state.test;
```

The products constant refers to array of products in state.

Then you can use products [i].name to access name of products.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just:

```
const products = this.state.test.products
```

without destructuring or two level destructuring and everything?

Simplicity is better.